# update on blur not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, blur

I have created a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/jimmymain/pen/kCztw) of this problem [here](http://codepen.io/jimmymain/pen/kCztw).

I have the following angular markup:
(*I have shortened the code snippet here, the full code can be seen in the pen*).

My problem is that the model is being updated on every **keypress** rather than only when the **input box is blurred**. I am not sure what I have missed?

I actually want the directive(s) to also be triggered on the blur, they are watching the model. I have tried a few combinations of `default` and `blur`.

```
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='PController'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="top" ng-repeat-start="person in people">
        <td colspan='3'>{{ person.Name }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="item in person.Items">
        <td>{{ item.AName }}</td>
        <td><input 
          ng-model="item.A" updateana
          ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 1000} }" />
          {{ item.A }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>    
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngModelOptions` is available since version 1.3.0-beta.6. Your plunker uses 1.2.20. If that's the version you're using in your project, there is no `ngModelOptions` available yet.

Here's an issue with a similar problem: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7117

Please read the bottom comment by @ggondim (at least "bottom" as of today, July 28th, 2014):

> A common confusion when reading docs is the selected version in the
>   dropdown before the breadcrumb. I think it should be selected with the
>   latest stable version and not latest beta.

You probably did the same: assumed the docs by default show the latest stable version, while instead they show the latest beta.

Comment: and it works 'oh so very well' when you use the correct version of angular... I have updated the codepen.